# r count cells with missing values across each row

Tags: r, count, missing-data

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
    Id         Date         Col1       Col2     Col3        Col4
    30         2012-03-31              A42.2    20.46        NA  
    36         1996-11-15   NA                  V73          55
    96         2010-02-07   X48        Z16      13
    40         2010-03-18   AD14                20.12        36
    69         2012-02-21              22.45                     
    11         2013-07-03   81         V017                  TCG11         
    22         2001-06-01                       67
    83         2005-03-16   80.45      V22.15   46.52        X29.11 
    92         2012-02-12   
    34         2014-03-10   82.12      N72.22   V45.44
```

I am trying to count the number of `NA` or **Empty cells** across each row and the final expected output is as follows

```
    Id         Date         Col1       Col2     Col3        Col4       MissCount
    30         2012-03-31              A42.2    20.46        NA        2
    36         1996-11-15   NA                  V73          55        2
    96         2010-02-07   X48        Z16      13                     1
    40         2010-03-18   AD14                20.12        36        1
    69         2012-02-21              22.45                           3
    11         2013-07-03   81         V017                  TCG11     1    
    22         2001-06-01                       67                     3
    83         2005-03-16   80.45      V22.15   46.52        X29.11    0
    92         2012-02-12                                              4   
    34         2014-03-10   82.12      N72.22   V45.44                 1
```

The last column `MissCount` will store the number of `NAs` or empty cells for each row. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Probably something like `rowSums(is.na(df) | df == "")` will do

Comment: it could be solved at input stage by having `read.table("filename",sep=",",na.strings=c("",,NA),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, this will result in only NA values and you can use @DavidArenburg solution to count all NA's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
yourframe$MissCount = rowSums(is.na(yourframe) | yourframe == "" | yourframe == " "))
```

Comment: I think you forgot to check for empty string.

Comment: @burton030, thanks that worked.

Answer (score 7):

The one-liner

```
rowSums(is.na(df) | df == "")
```

given by @DavidArenburg in his comment is definitely the way to go, assuming that you don't mind checking every column in the data frame.  If you really only want to check `Col1` through `Col4`, then using an `apply` function might make more sense.

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) {
                sum(is.na(x[c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4")])) +
                sum(x[c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4")] == "", na.rm=TRUE)
             })
```

Edit: Shortened code

```
apply(df[c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4")], 1, function(x) {
                    sum(is.na(x)) +
                    sum(x == "", na.rm=TRUE)
                 })
```

or if data columns are exactly like the example data:

```
apply(df[3:6], 1, function(x) {
                        sum(is.na(x)) +
                        sum(x == "", na.rm=TRUE)
                     })
```

Comment: I think you could shorten the code to `apply(df[c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4")], 1, function(x)` and then within the function just call the `x`, right? Or, if the data is structured as in the example, just `apply(df[3:6], 1, function(x)`

Comment: @LeoP. Feel free to make an edit in this case.  I just wanted to make the point that the columns would have to be specified _somewhere_ (though your suggestion might be a bit less ugly than mine ^ ^).

Answer (score 1):

You can use by_row from library purrr:

```
library(purrr)

#sample data frame
x <- data.frame(A1=c(1,NA,3,NA),
                A2=c("A","B"," ","C"),
                A3=c(" "," ",NA,"t"))
```

Here you apply a function on each row, you can edit it according to your condition. And you can use whatever function you want.
In the following example, I counted empty or NA entries in each row by using sum(...):

```
by_row(x, function(y) sum(y==" "| (is.na(y))),
       .to="MissCount",
       .collate = "cols"
       )
```

You will get:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     A1     A2     A3 MissCount
  <dbl> <fctr> <fctr>     <int>
1     1      A                1
2    NA      B                2
3     3            NA         2
4    NA      C      t         1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
Reduce(`+`, lapply(df, function(x) is.na(x)|!nzchar(as.character(x))))
```